# PyTest : dynamically generating test name during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, parametrized-testing

I want to name the test dynamically during run-time when i run them with the `@pytest.mark.parametrize("value",values_list)` fixture.
for example:

```
values_list=['apple','tomatoes','potatoes']

@pytest.mark.parametrize("value",values_list)
def test_xxx(self,value):
    assert value==value
```

the final outcome i want to see is 3 tests with the following names:

*test_apple*

*test_tomatoes*

*test_potatoes*

i gave tried looking in to pytest documentation but i haven found anything that might shed light on this problem.

Comment: You cannot do this.  All you can is to set custom name for every option in `parametrize` values by setting `ids` arguments. Take a look at  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids (test `test_timedistance_v1`). You can customize the value displayed in square brackets during test run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the names displayed in test execution by rewriting the `_nodeid` attibute of the test item. Example: create a file named `conftest.py` in your project/test root dir with the following contents:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        # check that we are altering a test named `test_xxx`
        # and it accepts the `value` arg
        if item.originalname == 'test_xxx' and 'value' in item.fixturenames:
            item._nodeid = item.nodeid.replace(']', '').replace('xxx[', '')
```

Running your tests will now yield

```
test_fruits.py::test_apple PASSED
test_fruits.py::test_tomatoes PASSED
test_fruits.py::test_potatoes PASSED
```

Beware that overwriting `_nodeid` should be enjoyed with caution as each nodeid should remain unique. Otherwise, `pytest` will silently drop executing some tests and it will be hard to find out why.

Comment: Thanks will try that and will let you know

Comment: Great it worked , but now i want to add another layer of complexity.
Let's say that :


```
values_list=[{'apple':'5'},{'tomatoes':'1'},{'potatoes': '32}]
```


I want the name of the test to be test_5, test_1 and so on , is there a way to access those values ? I've tried doing that via the setup_method in the test class itself, but i cant access the dictionary from there (even in debug).

Comment: Thanks in advance but i managed to figure it out , it took some digging but eventually i've discovered it was sitting in a nsested structure inside :             iitem.own_markers[0].args[1]
So i did some maniuplation with that data and managed to extract the required field